# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, modernizr

So, I have looked over the whole of stackoverflow to find an answer for my question and haven't found anything.  I tried to rewrite the .htaaccess like everyone had suggested and it didn't work.

I think the problem is that it is trying to read the web page as an image.

All the other links on my site except for http://anarrayofstars.com/temp/portfolio/bar-isabel/ and http://anarrayofstars.com/temp/.  Even my root level site anarrayofstars.com, works. Which is making me believe that it is something on one of these pages but I have looked over both of them many of times.

The main error is:

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://anarrayofstars.com/temp/portfolio/bar-isabel/".

Then the sub errors are:

```
(anonymous function)modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4 
y modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4 
s.touchmodernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4 
(anonymous function)modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4 
(anonymous function)modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
```

I don't know if that will help, but those are the errors I am receiving when I use chrome inspector, and for the life of me I cannot figure out where to find these errors.

Comment: You'll see this if you have that URL in an `<img>` tag or CSS `background-image` directive.

Comment: This is the reason - empty url for background-image, so modernizr tries to load it as current url `<nav class="main-d-nav iefix" style="background-image:url()">`

Comment: where did you find this cheery? and thanks.